# Regular Expressions Struts 1.3 Action Mapping

Tags: java, struts, struts-1, struts-config, action-mapping

I am working on a project using Struts 1.3 from what I can tell, given that this is at the top of the struts-config-default.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN" 
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
```

Is there any way to go about mapping a wildcard for an action forward to a jsp file? I have tried all sorts of wildcard variations:

```
<action path="/hello/candy" type="com.officedepot.globalweb.framework.action.ForwardDisplayAction">
        <forward name="success" path="/WEB-INF/jsp/candyStore.jsp" />
    </action>
```

I have a single page application that gets loaded in the 'candyStore.jsp' so i would like all and any URIs after /hello/candy to route to the same JSP. (eg. www.site.com/hello/candy/pageOne, www.site.com/hello/candy/33/jellybean, www.site.com/hello/candy/test all should forward to the jsp candyStore)

Is this at all possible using Struts 1.3 or should I be writing all the possible routes :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your action file

```
public ActionForward unspecified(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws Exception{


        //Perform any code here like error 404.
        return mapping.findForward("unspecified");
    }
```

In your struts action path in config file

```
<forward name="unspecified" path="/candyStore.jsp"/>
```

Comment: If it does not solve what you meant, please comment and i'll delete the answer. I could not have posted in the comments because of a long answer. Or else I would've.

Answer (score 0):

About 30 seconds on Google:

https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-example/struts-wildcards-in-action-mapping-example.html

```
<action-mappings>
  <action path="/*Action" type="com.vaannila.reports.{1}Action" name="{1}Form">
    <forward name="success" path="/{1}.jsp" />
  </action>
</action-mappings>
```

You would not require the wildcard in the forward's `path`.